# Optimizing Keyword Weights for a Web Crawler

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, modeling

I'm playing around with writing a web crawler that scans for a specific set of keywords and then assigns a global score to each domain it encounters based on a cumulative score I assigned to each keyword (programming=1, clojure=2, javascript=-1, etc...).

I have set up my keyword scoring on a sliding scale of -10 to 10 and I have based my initial values on my own assumptions about what is and is not relevant.

I feel that my scoring model may be flawed, and I would prefer to feed a list of domains that match the criteria I'm trying to capture into an analysis tool and optimize my keyword weights based on some kind of statistical analysis.

What would be an appropriate analysis technique to generate an optimal scoring model for a list of "known good domains"? Is this problem suited for bayesian learning, monte carlo simulation, or some other technique?

Comment: Basically you are saying that you have an example set of good domains, and you want to find other domains that are similar based on their content?   Do you also have negative domains?  It seems like a typical supervised learning/document classification task, where here your target "documents" are the collection of docs from a given domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, given a training set of relevant and irrelevant domains, you'd like to build a model which classifies new domains to one of these categories. I assume the features you will be using are the terms appearing in the domains, i.e. this is can be framed as a [document classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification%E2%80%8E)  problem.

Generally, you are correct in assuming that letting statistical-based machine learning algorithms to do the "scoring" for you works better than assigning manual scores to keywords.

A simple way to approach the problem would be to using Bayesian learning, and specifically, Naive Bayes might be a good fit.

After generating a dataset from the domains you've manually tagged (e.g. collecting several pages from each domain and treating each as a document), you can experiment various algorithms using one of the machine learning frameworks, e.g. [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/).

A primer on how to handle and load text documents to WEKA can be found [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+Weka). After the data is loaded, you can use the framework to experiment with various classification algorithms, e.g. Naive  Bayes, SVM, etc. Once you've found the method best fitting your needs, you can export the resulting model and use it via WEKA's Java API.

Comment: Thank you. This gives me a good starting point for attacking the scoring issue.